# RadioGroup in TouchUI Component

Tags: aem

I was developing touch UI component. Below is what i tried and worked at some extent. Below is dialog.xml

```
<content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <herotext
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="Hero Text Properties"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <myradiogroup
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radiogroup"
                                fieldLabel="Select Fruit"
                                name="./fruit">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <option1
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
                                        cq-msm-lockable="fruit"
                                        renderReadOnly="{Boolean}true"
                                        text="Apple"
                                        value="apple"/>
                                    <option2
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio"
                                        cq-msm-lockable="fruit"
                                        renderReadOnly="{Boolean}true"
                                        text="Pear"
                                        value="pear"/>
                                </items>
                            </myradiogroup>
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </herotext>
        </items>
    </content>
```

After this I am able to render the radio selected value on the page. But having below issue.

```
1) Radio options are coming in vertical direction, but i want them in horizontal.
2) Radio Group Name not display, I want same like as fieldLabel & want to hide hide the border line.
3) When i reopen the dialog, radiobutton is not selected even if the selected value stored in JCR during last submit.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For getting the Radio Buttons in horizontal direction use following class as property with `coral-RadioGroup--horizontal` value. This is the OOTB class provided by AEM, you can also have your custom class to control layout and alignment

For displaying the [Radio Button Group](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radiogroup/index.html) label use `text` property.

[image: Radio Button Group properties]

On opening the dialog, properties are populating fine. See if you have any other radiobuttongroup in same dialog with same name.